# Sharepoint Site Office 365 - Hiding Group Member view

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, groups, office

Is there a way to hide and revoke the ability for site visitors to see and add group members? I found a setting that looked like it would do this, but when I changed it, it did nothing.  The Setting I talking about is in "Site Permissions", then "Advanced" and "Access Request Settings"
I have an education account.

Answer (score 0):

If the person can see group membership, and especially if they can add group members, then they're not a site visitor, they have a higher privilege.

You can check the permission of an individual person by:

1. Site Settings > Site Permissions;
2. In the ribbon, choose Check Permissions;
3. Type the person's name, then it will tell you which groups they're a member of;

Rather directly: if you wan to protect an individual group for whatever reason (say Approvers who are anon) you can limit who can see the group membership of a specific group, navigate to that Group list:

1. using the toolbar, click Settings > Group Settings;
2. In the Group Settings page, you can govern who sees your group membership.

On the Access Request Settings dialog box will only show you if members of your team site can add other members.